# Access location permission from another Activity

Tags: android, gps, location

I have a class which checks the location permission and show the dialog if not granted and its working fine if I run it separately but when I try to use it in another class it gave me the exception

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread
> android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object
> reference"

This is my class :

```
public class LocSettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID = 3;

    private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loc_setting);

        initGoogleAPIClient(this);//Init Google API Client
 
    }

    /* Initiate Google API Client  */
    private void initGoogleAPIClient(Context context) {
        //Without Google API Client Auto Location Dialog will not work
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /* Check Location Permission for Marshmallow Devices */
    public void checkPermissions(Context context) {

        initGoogleAPIClient(context);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestLocationPermission();
            else
                showSettingDialog();
        } else
            showSettingDialog();

    }

    /*  Show Popup to access User Permission  */
    public void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LocSettingActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocSettingActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocSettingActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);
        }
    }

    /* Show Location Access Dialog */
    public void showSettingDialog() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);//Setting priotity of Location request to high
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);//5 sec Time interval for location update
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient to show dialog always when GPS is off

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
//                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(LocSettingActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case RESULT_OK:
                        Log.e("Settings", "Result OK");
//                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                        //startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.e("Settings", "Result Cancel");
//                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Disabled in your device");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));//Register broadcast receiver to check the status of GPS
        checkPermissions(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Unregister receiver on destroy
        if (gpsLocationReceiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver);
    }

    //Run on UI
    public Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showSettingDialog();
        }
    };

    //     Broadcast receiver to check status of GPS
    private BroadcastReceiver gpsLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                //If Action is Location
                if (intent.getAction().matches(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    //Check if GPS is turned ON or OFF
                    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                        Log.e("About GPS", "GPS is Enabled in your device");
//                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                    } else {
                        //If GPS turned OFF show Location Dialog
                        new Handler().postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);
                        // showSettingDialog();
//                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Disabled in your device");
                        checkPermissions(context);
                        Log.e("About GPS", "GPS is Disabled in your device");
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    //Method to update GPS status text
    private void updateGPSStatus(Context context,String status) {
        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /* On Request permission method to check the permisison is granted or not for Marshmallow+ Devices  */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        try {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID: {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //If permission granted show location dialog if APIClient is not null
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            initGoogleAPIClient(this);
                            showSettingDialog();
                        } else
                            showSettingDialog();


                    } else {
//                        updateGPSStatus("Location Permission denied.");
                        Toast.makeText(LocSettingActivity.this, "Location Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        simpleAlertGps();
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void simpleAlertGps() {
        try {
            android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Your Gps Must Be On For Better Result");
            alertDialog.setButton(android.app.AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            try {
                            /*Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);*/
                                checkPermissions(LocSettingActivity.this);

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(LocSettingActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here I'm getting it in other class

```
 LocSettingActivity locSettingActivity = new LocSettingActivity();

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       
            locSettingActivity.checkPermissions(this);
         
    }
 public void openTuckLocation(View view) {
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            in=new Intent(PagerMainActivity.this, MapsActivityLocation.class);

         }
        else {
            locSettingActivity.checkPermissions(this);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you are using to get locatin use location permission into public class and import it where you want to accress location

Comment: I'm only taking the permission in this class not anything else

Answer (score 0):

insted of

```
locSettingActivity.checkPermissions(this);
```

use

```
locSettingActivity.checkPermissions(getApplicationContext);
```

Or

```
locSettingActivity.checkPermissions(ActivityName.this);
```

as sometimes context can also give error